# Eclipselink caching problem (one database for two systems)

Tags: caching, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have two online-systems running. Both of them are using eclipselink.

The first system is a administration-system, where the prices for the second application are managed.
The second system is a online shop, where customer can buy articles.
Both of them run on the same server and use the same oracle database.

To provide a fast access, the price-objects are cached by eclipselink.

If I change the value of a price in the administration-system, the shop-system should flush its cache in order to get the new price value.
What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem but it's with user credentials.

**1) Configure caching in the shop-side**

You can configure the EclipseLink caching to have an expiry.  You can configure it to have a 
TimeToLive or an expire at value.  For example you could configure prices to expire after 1, 5 or 10 minutes.  Not instant, but pretty quick and very easy to implement.  Check out the @Cache annotation in EclipseLink.  This is what I ended up using.

**2) Have the admin application communicate with the shop application**

It might be worth creating a web-service that lives in the shop side which will invalidate the cache when called.  Kinda fragile but might be necessary depending on your setup.

**3) Use Cache co-ordination**

EclipseLink has functionality for cache co-ordination.  I have never used it but it looks like it might be best policy for you.  You can check out the EclipseLink documentation for more information.

Comment: Option 3 seems to be the best for my case. Do you know a good tutorial, how to manage this on a tomcat container via RMI? The EclipseLink documentation isn´t very detailed in that point and google knows only bugs about it ;)

Comment: I don't have any experience with that.  You could try the eclipselink mailing lists.  If anyone would know, it would be them.